# Is it possible to convert a similarity (distance) index to correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation, distance, similarities

I have two cases that each one has some values on a series of variables (e.g. A, B & C). Is it possible to calculate a distance or similarity index between these two cases and then convert it to a correlation coefficient between the two cases?

Comment: A correlation coefficient typically is computed (and makes sense) to measure association between variables. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I simply want to obtain **a** correlation coefficient between my cases based on values of all variables which are more than two (at least three).

Comment: May I ask you why? I don't see why a distance metric is not enough... Maybe by _convert it to a correlation coefficient between the two cases_ you mean something I fail to grasp.